# ionic build android error

Tags: android, cordova, build, ionic-framework

I'm confused. jdk,sdk,ant,cordova,ionic doing well,why builds error?
I searched everywhere,but no answer for it.
I guess has a error version?
who can help this?

system:win8
  jdk:1.8
  ant:1.96
  android:22

```
%ANT_HOME%\bin\;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools\;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\;%java_home%\bin;%java_home%\jre\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

Path

```
E:\ionic\demo22>ionic build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" E:\ionic\demo22\hooks\after_
prepare\010_add_platform_class.js E:\ionic\demo22
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "E:\ionic\demo22\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat
""
ANDROID_HOME=E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
Running: E:\ionic\demo22\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b E:\ionic\dem
o22\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
Unzipping C:\Users\cxt\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-all\2m8005s69iu8v0oiej
fej094b\gradle-2.2.1-all.zip to C:\Users\cxt\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-
all\2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094b
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipExceptio
n: error in opening zip file
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:78)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:65)
        ... 3 more

E:\ionic\demo22\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "E:\ionic\demo22\platforms\androi
d\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b E:\ionic\demo22\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.
gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\cxt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cord
ova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to install

1. node.js
2. apache ANT
3. JDK & JRE
4. Android SDK & Eclipse

After installation, you have to set software paths into environmental- variable. Then fire your `npm install -g cordova`. Without this **PhoneGap** will not be created.

If still you have any confusion or question related to software installation then tell me.

Comment: thx.  I soved it, cause this :  ` java.util.zip.ZipExceptio
n: error in opening zip`  the broken zip file~

Comment: How did you solve this problem? Can you please explain it further?

Comment: This cannot be the answer... Daniel Pérez has a better solution.

Answer (score 12):

I hope that not too late, but I had the same error and. So, I fixed it doing the next:

In your case find this:

> C:\Users\cxt\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-
> all\2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094b

now you are here to delete the gradle-2.2.1-all.zip because this file is corrupted and then replace the file with this http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
when you finish all try again

> ionic build android

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Mac. 
The steps below solved that for me:

> NOTE: gradle path & version would be different on your machine. please replace those informations with yours. you can get them from exception message

- Download : http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip
- Get List of files in directory

> sudo ls rm /var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.13-all/7hsc6vr6mi3i6i5m7q9hj4ci1q

- Remove existing zip file

> sudo rm /var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.13-all/7hsc6vr6mi3i6i5m7q9hj4ci1q/gradle-2.13-all.zip

- If there is a *.zip.lck file, you'd better remove that too..

> sudo rm /var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.13-all/7hsc6vr6mi3i6i5m7q9hj4ci1q/gradle-2.13-all.zip.lck

- Copy downloaded file to that path

> sudo cp /Downloads/gradle-2.13-all.zip /var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.13-all/7hsc6vr6mi3i6i5m7q9hj4ci1q/

Then try to run

> ionic run android