# Ionic error on android emulate

Tags: java, ionic-framework, hybrid

I have installed java JRE but i keep on getting. Am using windows 10 for development

After running ionic run android or ionic emulate android i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:159)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
    at     org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    ... 3 more
```

I have also set JRE_HOME in the environment variables

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325202/java-util-zip-zipexception-error-in-opening-zip-file could be of your interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is related to something missing or corrupted.
You can find a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153915/ionic-build-android-error), hope it helps.

> First of all you have to install
>
> 1. node.js
> 2. apache ANT
> 3. JDK & JRE
> 4. Android SDK & Eclipse
>
> After installation, you have to set software paths into environmental- variable. Then fire your npm install -g cordova. Without this PhoneGap will not be created.