# Cordova Build Failure - NullPointerException

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, phonegap

When i try to build a Cordova Android App it replies with

[image: ERROR Message]

> > The Environmental variables are : 
> >     ANDROID_SDK_ROOT --> C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
> >     JAVA_HOME --> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191
> >     PATH -->
> >     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;
> >     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;
> >     C:\Gradle\gradle-5.5\bin;
> >     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin

& all cordova requirements are fulfilled 
 [image: Cordova Requirements]

So can you help me what is the solution here, and thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Its a network issue, the gradle will not download if you're in a proxy network

Comment: I don't think so , I've added gradle and edited file "C:\h\platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\projectbuilders.js" var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'file:\\\C:\Gradle\gradle-5.5-all.zip'; <br> Also all cordova requirements are fulfilled

Comment: can you check  the environment variables is set correctly?

Comment: Thanks Ramachandran :) , But i set it as written in the question,i think all are right

Comment: Did you this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153915/ionic-build-android-error

Answer (score 1):

I think it's works for above error

Please Copy templates folder From here--C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\ And paste To here--C:\Users\your User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\

Comment: I have recognized it,but what is the solution ?!!

Comment: I have copied it but nothing is new :(